# Url generation error Rails : No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a link calling my notes which belong to my notebook like so:

```
 == link_to "#{note.title.upcase}", notebook_note_path(note), id:  "note_name"
```

I don't know why I am getting the error.

here is my routes:

```
resources :notebooks do
  resources :notes
end
```

Comment: Have you created `notebook_note_path` in routes.rb?

Comment: i just edited the q with my routes. I think the routes are correct unless I am misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have nested routes, you need to **pass two objects** to the helper method. Rather than just a `note`, try passing a `notebook` and a `note`:

```
notebook_note_path(note.notebook, note)
```

For reference, take a look at the output from `rake routes` when you have the `routes.rb` set up as you do:

```
notebook_notes GET    /notebooks/:notebook_id/notes(.:format)          notes#index
                   POST   /notebooks/:notebook_id/notes(.:format)          notes#create
 new_notebook_note GET    /notebooks/:notebook_id/notes/new(.:format)      notes#new
edit_notebook_note GET    /notebooks/:notebook_id/notes/:id/edit(.:format) notes#edit
     notebook_note GET    /notebooks/:notebook_id/notes/:id(.:format)      notes#show
                   PATCH  /notebooks/:notebook_id/notes/:id(.:format)      notes#update
                   PUT    /notebooks/:notebook_id/notes/:id(.:format)      notes#update
                   DELETE /notebooks/:notebook_id/notes/:id(.:format)      notes#destroy
...
```

Since the URI for this path is `/notebooks/:notebook_id/notes/:id`, there must be both a notebook id and a note id (Rails replaces the ones with a colon in front of them with the id of a resource passed into the helper method).